# Sorting/condensing large CSV file by multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, csv

So the csv file I'm working with looks like:

```
Date Time,            SegmentID,   indicatorvalue
2016-12-01T00:00:00Z  147649       1
2016-12-01T00:01:00Z  147649       0
2016-12-01T00:02:00Z  147649       1
...                   ...          ...
2016-12-01T00:23:00Z  2938733      0
```

ect.

What I want is to condense it down into a list of all the segments, and then a percentage of how many of the entries for that segment have the indicatorvalue, banded by time of day(AM/IP/PM/OP)

eg:

```
segmentID,  Time Period,  Percentage
147649      AM            78
147649      IP            100
147649      PM            60
147649      OP            30
243546      AM            79
243546      IP            98
...         ...           ...
```

My attempt was to set up a for loop, so that for each segment it would keep a running total of the indicator percentages for the 4 times of day, then once it had detected it had changed to a new segmentID it would append those values to a string.

The problem is that the segmentIDs are unordered, leading to multiple entries for the same segmentID. I tried ordering the file by SegmentID but the file is far too massive. Any suggestions on an alternate approach?

EDIT:
Someone who has deleted their comment posted that I should use Pandas, so after a bit of research my code is currently:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("data.csv",sep=",",index_col="Segment ID",usecols=["Segment ID","Date Time","indicatorvalue"])
df['Date Time'] = ['AM' if '06' <= x[11:13] < '10' 
    else 'IP' if '10' <= x[11:13] < '16' 
    else 'PM' if '16' <= x[11:13] < '19'
    else 'OP' if '19' <= x[11:13] or x[11:13] < '06'
    else 'Error' for x in df['Date Time']]
```

Now I just need to work out how to condense rows with duplicate entries for 'Date Time' and 'SegmentID', while averaging their 'indicatorvalues'.

Comment: How massive is massive?

Comment: About 3.5GB, not sure how many rows but in the millions

Comment: And how much memory is available, and how many segments are expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out a solution with pandas. The code I used was:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("data.csv",sep=",",usecols=["Segment ID","Date Time","indicator value"])

df['Date Time'] = ['AM' if '06' <= x[11:13] < '10' 
   else 'IP' if '10' <= x[11:13] < '16' 
   else 'PM' if '16' <= x[11:13] < '19'
   else 'OP' if '19' <= x[11:13] or x[11:13] < '06'
   else 'Error' for x in df['Date Time']]

grouped = df.groupby(['Segment ID','Date Time']).mean() 

grouped.to_csv('output.csv', sep =',')
```

I cannot recommend Pandas enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the structure of the input file is one line per minute giving the starting time, the segment id and the value of the indicator.

If the number of the segment is compatible with the available memory, I would just read the input file on line at a time, and add minutes to 8 counters per segment, that is per time of day and indicator value. That means that the initial file is only read once, not sorted, and the only critical quantity is the number of segments - if it becomes too high, I would use a sqlite3 or dbm database instead of a dict.

With your current example (with is **not** a csv), code could be:

```
class Segment:
    labels = ['AM', 'IP', 'PM', 'OP']
    def __init__(self, segid):
        self.id = segid
        self.values = [ [ 0, 0 ] for i in range(4) ]
    def add(self, hour, indic):
        ix = 3
        if hour >= 6 and hour < 10: ix=0
        elif hour >= 10 and hour < 16: ix=1
        elif hour >= 16 and hour < 19: ix = 2
        self.values[ix][indic] += 1
    def percent(self, ix):
        try:
            return int(.5 + (100 * self.values[ix][1] /
                 (self.values[ix][0] + self.values[ix][1])))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return 0

dummy = next(fd)
splitter = re.compile(' +')
segments = dict()
for line in fd:  # read and store
    d, seg, indic = splitter.split(line.strip())  # could be replaced with a csv reader
    hour = int(d[11:13])
    if not seg in segments:
        segments[seg] = Segment(seg)
    segments[seg].add(hour, int(indic))
for seg in sorted(segments.keys()):  # output the stats
    for ix in range(4):
        print(seg, Segment.labels[ix], segments[seg].percent(ix))
```

Above code lacks tests for error or exceptional conditions